# XSLT: Skip both elements if duplicates are detected

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML similar to this:

```
<elements>
  <element>
     <value>1</value>
  </element>
  <element>
     <value>1</value>
  </element>
</elements>
```

If more than a single `<element>` has a value of 1, I want to skip all `<element>` elements. In other words, my new XML structure does not allow for two or more `<element>` elemements to have the same `<value>` value.

Is there a way to get XSL to acheive this? The "preceding" test doesn't seem to be what I need, so I could use some advice on how to approach this issue.

Comment: The latter - I want to skip all `<element>` elements if they have `<value>`. I'll update my post to make this clear.

Comment: With XSLT questions, please always specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. For grouping questions in particular (which this is) the solutions are typically very different.

Comment: You say: "If more than a single `<element>` has a value of 1, I want to skip all <element> elements". So if there are two elements with value 1 and one with value 2, you want to skip all three? What if there is one element with value 1 and two elements with value 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet removes all occurrences of `<element>` elements if they appear more than one times. The *identity template* just copies the rest of the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="doubles" match="element" use="value" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:if test="count(key('doubles',value)) &lt; 2">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input XML the output is:

```
<elements>      
</elements>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete example!